# Pick random value based on list of probabilities

Tags: probability-or-statistics, sampling

I'm pretty sure this must have been asked before, but I can not find the duplicate.

Given a list of values with their probabilities

```
probabilities = {{1500, 0.037000000000000005`}, {2500, 0.027000000000000003`}, {3500, 
   0.039`}, {4500, 0.07400000000000001`}, {5500, 0.073`}, {6500, 
   0.08199999999999999`}, {7500, 0.092`}, {8500, 0.096`}, {9500, 
   0.095`}, {10500, 0.09`}, {11500, 0.078`}, {12500, 0.065`}, {13500, 
   0.051`}, {14500, 0.037000000000000005`}, {15500, 
   0.026000000000000002`}, {16500, 0.017`}, {17500, 0.01`}, {18500, 
   0.006`}, {19500, 0.003`}, {20500, 0.002`}};
```

How can I draw a random value from this list with the given probability? I'd wager a guess that you could somehow model a PDF based on this and use it with functions like `RandomVariate[]`.

Comment: Look at `RandomChoice`.

Comment: @ChrisK That was what I was looking for thanks! If you'd like the points, post it as an answer (no code example needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];

RandomChoice[WeightedData @@ Transpose[probabilities], 5]
```

> ```
> {12500, 4500, 12500, 5500, 5500}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
SeedRandom[1];

RandomChoice[#2 -> # & @@ Transpose[probabilities], 5]
```

> ```
> {12500, 4500, 12500, 5500, 5500}
> ```